# Firebase Hosting Github Actions: Unable to populate apis into website

Tags: firebase, deployment, github-actions, github-api, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase and github actions for hosting and deployment but my website is not getting populated with apis I have even created seperate environment for secrets and variables to pinpoint the error. But still nothing is happening.

Here is the yml file.

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
concurrency: production
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - sa
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
             flutter-version: '3.16.5'
             channel: 'stable'
      - name: Create .env file
        run: |
         --url for env variable--
       

      - name: Merge to branch
        run: |
          git checkout sa
      - name: Print .env file
        run: cat .env

      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build web
     

      - name: Upload Build Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: web-build
          path: build/web

      - name: Debug Secret
        run: echo "Firebase Service Account:${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"

      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: app
        env:
               FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```